# How to use .htaccess to block Russian IP addresses?

Tags: htaccess

I added this code to my `.htaccess` file

```
#deny all russian IP's
Order allow,deny
deny from .ru
Allow from all
```

My questions:

1. **Can it go anywhere in the file?** I added it to the end.
2. **Do I put the code in the root `.htaccess` file?** I have lots of `.htaccess` files; they are all over the place with a Prestashop site.

[image]

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you want that?

Comment: I have a russian bot sending hundreds of messages on my contact page - its crashing my site and making it unusable for all my customers. I installed a SlideCaptcha but it appears to be able to go round it.

Comment: So you do realize that you're blocking the whole large top-level domain in order to block something that is very likely to go on spamming you from a different segment? :-O

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Can it go anywhere in the file?**

Yes and no. In general, if you have added it to the end of the file, it should be fine. But the reason I say “yes and no” is without knowing the rest of the contents of the `.htaccess` file it’s impossible to give a definite answer. For all I know you have other `allow`/`deny` directives that might interfere with this one.

> **Do I put the code in the root .htaccess file?**

Yes! It should go in the root. I am not completely clear on the logic of the other `.htaccess` files in a Prestashop site, but I cannot imaging those non-root `.htaccess` files will interfere. In general an `.htaccess` file at the root will cover all other paths beneath it.

That said, this kind of “hunt and peck” method does not effectively work since you need to constantly update it; it’s going to give you more headaches than it is worth.

Instead, if you are a system administrator and know how to use [IPtables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iptables) and [IPSec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPsec) then those tools are better alternatives to blocking whole IP ranges. They are faster, more robust and more flexible than just hacking away at `.htaccess` files endlessly. [This thread on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/772028/howto-configure-ipset-to-block-entire-countries-ips) explains the basics of doing country-bass IP address blocking using IPsec and IPtables and is worth a look.

But, again, since these are really deeper level OS tools for IP blocking, if you are not comfortable using tools like this, you might be better off just using `.htaccess` for the time being.

Comment: Just worth remembering - using iptables and such would look like your site isn't there. In theory, while his approach feels totally wrong, you might get an actual error message if his web server goes "eh, this russian ip. GO AWAY!"

Answer (score 0):

I think... you don't quite get the relationship between IP addresses and domain names. Firstly *typically*, unless you explicitly set it up that way, one or more domains map to an ip address, not the other way around, and when you *do* set up rdns - your typical web server dosen't care about it. In short .ru dosen't mean anything in this context to your webserver.

You might ask... "But what about geoblocking?" - well, you'd basically find a *list* of ip addresses - aka a geoip database, and use some tool to do the blocking for you.

A .htaccess file is really an override for a specific directory. Its worth remembering [apache actually dosen't recommend its use](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html). *If* you want to block something, it should presumably set up in the *main config file*

Mucking around a bit - you can apparently get htaccess files from the internet with a *list* of IP ranges - the one I generated [here](https://www.ip2location.com/free/visitor-blocker)'s about  3mb for Russia - and I'm unsure of the effects of throwing about large IP address ranges to block on your server